# How to count no of rows in table from web application using selenium python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to count the rows in the table from web application by using selenium python web driver. Here we can retrieve all data in the table from web application but couldn't count the rows and columns, please give me idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 21):

Try some thing like this

```
int rowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='DataTable']/tbody/tr")).size();

int columnCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='DataTable']/tbody/tr/td")).size();
```

FYI : This is the implementation in java.

Comment: i'm using python web driver. This size() function is not working there.

Comment: See this link : http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements_by_xpath -------> I think in python len is the method to find length/size of the list

Comment: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Answer (score 13):

Santoshsarma's answer is close to correct for Java, but it will count the number of cells rather than the number of columns. Here's a Python version that will count the number of columns in the first row:

```
row_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTable']/tbody/tr"))
column_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTable']/tbody/tr/td"))
```

If your table has a header you could count the columns there instead.

I haven't tried using storeXpathCount.

Comment: A tip for future readers: remember that `find_element` is different from `find_elements`. Spent some time asking myself why a WebElement had no len attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using [find_elements_by](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) or [execute_script](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=execute_script#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script).

Retrieving count by applying [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) on result of [find_elements_by](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) is correct way, however in other turn getting count of rows and columns by using [**execute_script**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) is **quite faster** then getting `len` from result of `find_elements_by` method call:

```
rows_count = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length")
columns_count = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('th').length")
```

Below is performance metrics of using **find_elements_by vs execute_script** approach:

```
from timeit import timeit

# Time metrics of retrieving 111 table rows
timeit(lambda:driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('tr').length"), number=1000)
# 5.525
timeit(lambda:len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")), number=1000) 
# 9.799
timeit(lambda:len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr")), number=1000)
# 10.656

# Time metrics of retrieving 5 table headers
timeit(lambda:driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('th').length"), number=1000)
# 5.441
timeit(lambda:len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("th")), number=1000)
8.604
timeit(lambda:len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/th")), number=1000)
# 9.336
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium has a function for counting the XPath result, see http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html. According to this you can use storeXpathCount.

I am using the DefaultSelenium class from the selenium-java-client-driver, where I can use (also in java) the following:

```
int rowCount = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='Datatable']/tbody/tr").intValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

For python users the simple way of counting a tag is as follows.

```
!#use find_elements_by_xpath

test_elem = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='host-history']/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr")

!#then check the len of the returnes list

print (len(test_elem))
```

Answer (score 1):

## As of 2022

The best way I found was as follow. Where my table has many tr elements

Get the full path and

```
path1="/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div/table/tbody"
element1=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,path1).find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr')
number_of_rows = len(element1)
```