# How to get the number of rows in of table?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the numbers of rows of a table on a web page using selenium python.
I tried the following way describe here: [How to count no of rows in table from web application using selenium python webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831041/how-to-count-no-of-rows-in-table-from-web-application-using-selenium-python-webd)

```
rows=len(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='SheetContentPlaceHolder_GridView1']/tbody/tr"))
```

The result I get is the following:

```
rows=len(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='SheetContentPlaceHolder_GridView1']/tbody/tr"))
TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()
```

I don't understand what I misdo.

Thanks for your help

Comment: For list use `find_elements_*`

Comment: "driver.find_elements_by_xpath": it's "elements"

Comment: indeed! that s a little s that change a lot! thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count no of rows in table from web application using selenium python webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831041/how-to-count-no-of-rows-in-table-from-web-application-using-selenium-python-webd)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method `driver.find_element_by_xpath(...)` returns you only the first child (row) of the table.

Change the line to `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(...)`. It returns a list of elements. So the new code will be:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='SheetContentPlaceHolder_GridView1']/tbody/tr")
number_of_rows = len(rows)
```

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_xpath()` would return a single element and as you were using *FireFox*, the first matching [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) was returned which can be passed to `len()`. Hence you see the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()
```

So instead of `find_element_by_xpath()` you need to to use `find_elements_by_xpath()` which would return a *List*.

---

Ideally, to extract the number of rows in js table using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and Python you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='SheetContentPlaceHolder_GridView1']/tbody/tr")))))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```